# Testing for the existence of a resource given its relative URI

Tags: java, uri

I wrote a little Java servlet that would dynamically generate an image button given parameters including label, height, width and so on, and it would add each new one to a cache. It worked fine, BUT it required a servlet call for every call to display the button or its highlighted version. I dumped the cache and made PNG files of all the buttons used at the moment in the app, added those files to the app so they could be referenced by "/images/button/xyz.png", where the filename is a hash of the input parameters.

That works fine, but I want my original servlet to be called on the occasion when someone has added a new button. I use a custom tag to define these buttons, so the tag handler gets called when the JSP compiles... so I have a point where I can choose to use one of the pre-generated buttons, OR generate a reference to the servlet so it can render the button when it is displayed.

My question is: How can I detect the image is available in pre-rendered for? I'm not sure that a call to create a URL object based off the full path and then doing a call to getResource() is the answer -- I don't want it to load the image at this time, I just need to know if it exists.

Is there some way to create a File object that would take a relative URI and allow me to test for existence?

Comment: For now, I have the resources duplicated -- one with the class, where it can be detected, and the other in our webroot. getResource just was not able to find it unless I placed it somewhere in the classpath -- which has been pointed out numerous times on this forum. I was just hoping to get outside the box a little. I know there's something I'm missing, and if I can figure it out, I'll amend this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about the `getResource()` method on `java.lang.Class` .  This is actually well-suited to the problem since [by contract](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)), it will return `null` if no resource exists with the given path.  The resource isn't actually loaded until you use `getResourceAsStream()` (or similar) so this is not a performance concern.

Comment: The issue, I believe, is that the image file is not on the classpath of my taglib. They are deployed to a different jar file. The images are relative to the web root, but even when I pass the fully-qualified URL to getResource (or to File), it isn't found.

Comment: Marking answered. This is good information about getResource; it didn't solve my problem, but I am not sure it can be solved in the way I would like it solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach in a utility class.

```
public static boolean imageExists(final String imageFileName) throws Exception{
        boolean status = false;
        HttpURLConnection  conn = null;
        URL url = new URL(imageFileName);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection )url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            String contentType = conn.getContentType();
        if(contentType.contains("image")){
            status = true;  
        }else{
            status = false; 
        }

        return status;
    }
```

This assumes your image file names are unique.